# PHP: Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php

Tenho um mini quiz a executar onde são perguntas diferentes caso seja homem ou mulher, consegui criar as perguntas usando radio buttons e seus value sendo "certa" e "errada" e no php usei algo em torno de "if(variavel == "certa"){ $resultado += +1}"

Super Quiz:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Super Quiz</title>
    <style> 
        h1{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Comic Sans,Helvetica,  fixedsys;
        }
        p{
            text-align: center;
        }
        #teste{
            padding-top: 5%;
            padding-left: 5%;
            padding-right: 5%;
            padding-bottom: 5%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "quiz.php" method = "post">  
        <div id="teste">
            <fieldset>  
                <h1> Super Quiz </h1>
                <br>
                <p>Nome: </p>
                <p><input type = "text" name = "nome" value = "" size="40" maxlength="40"> </p>
                <br>
                <p>Informe seu sexo:</p>
                <br>
                <p><input type ="radio" name = "sexo" value = "m" checked> MASCULINO </p>
                <br>
                <p><input type ="radio" name = "sexo" value = "f"> FEMININO </p>
                <br><br>
                <p><input type = "submit" value="Enviar"></p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Página PHP que verifica o sexo e imprime as perguntas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Super Perguntas </title>
    <style>
        h1{
            text-align: center;
            font-family:Comic-Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        p{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sexoEscolhido = $_POST['sexo'];        
    if($sexoEscolhido == "m")
        echo    "<h1> Seja bem vindo, $nome   </h1><br>";
    else
        echo    "<h1> Seja bem vinda, $nome   </h1><br>";
    echo "<br>" . $nome . ", responda a estas perguntas: <br><br>";
    if($sexoEscolhido == "m"){  
?>
    <form action="resultado.php" method ="post">
        <div id="teste">
            <p>Qual o time brasileiro tem mais mundiais?</p>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="um" value= "errada" checked>1- Santos </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="um" value = "errada">2- Corinthians </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="um" value = "certa">3- São Paulo </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="um" value = "errada">4- Palmeiras </p><br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Qual o nome do maior continente do mundo?</p>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="dois" value="certa" checked>1- Ásia </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="dois" value="errada">2- Oceania </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="dois" value="errada">3- America do Sul </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="dois" value="errada">4- Antartida </p><br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Qual o nome da espécie do Optimus Prime?</p>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="tres" value="errada" checked>1-Transformer </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="tres" value="errada">2-Autobots </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="tres" value="errada">3-Decepticons </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio"; name="tres" value="certa">4- Cybertroniano </p><br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </form> 
    <br>
<?php
    }
    else{
?>
    <form action = "resultado.php" method ="post">  
        <div id="teste">
            <p>Qual o nome da neta do Goku?</p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="um" value="certa" checked>1-Pan </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="um" value="errada">2-Videl </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="um" value="errada">3-Bulma </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="um" value="errada">4-Sakura </p><br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Qual o jogo mais jogado do mundo?</p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="dois" value="errada" checked>1-Counter Strike: Global Ofensive</p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="dois" value="certa">2-League of Legends</p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="dois" value="errada">3-Fortnite</p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="dois" value="errada">4-Transformice</p><br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Qual o último campeão do campeonato brasileiro, do ano de 2017?</p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="tres" value="errada" checked>1-Internacional </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="tres" value="errada">2-Santos </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="tres" value="errada">3-Palmeiras </p><br>
            <p><input type="radio" name="tres" value="certa">4-Corinthians </p><br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br>
<?php
    }
?>
    <br>
    <a href="index.php">
        <button>VOLTAR</button>
    </a>
    <a href="resultado.php"> 
        <button>RESULTADO</button>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Pagina que deveria conter o resultado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Super Quiz</title>
    <style> 
        h1{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Comic Sans,Helvetica,  fixedsys;
        }
        p{
            text-align: center;
        }
        #teste{
            padding-top: 5%;
            padding-left: 5%;
            padding-right: 5%;
            padding-bottom: 5%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //inicialização
    $um = "";
    $dois = "";
    $tres = "";
    $resultado = 0;

    //pegar variável do post
    $perguntaUm = $_POST["um"];
    $perguntaDois = $_POST["dois"];
    $perguntaTres = $_POST["tres"];

    //estrutura de verificação
    if($perguntaUm == "certa"){
        $resultado +=  +1;
    }
    if($perguntaDois == "certa"){
        $resultado +=  +1;
    }
    if($perguntaTres == "certa"){
        $resultado +=  +1;
    }
    echo $resultado;
?>

<?php
    echo
    "<form>
        <div id=\"teste\">
            <fieldset>
                <h1> Super Quiz </h1>
                <br>
                <p>Nome: </p>
                <br>
                <p>Neste quiz você acertou um total de: $resultado </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>";
?>
    <a href="index.php"> 
        <button>VOLTAR</button>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

O que acontece é o erro "Notice: Undefined index:" nas três variaveis que deveriam pegar o valor dos radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que o botão execute capturando as informações preenchidas no formulário de forma direta, ele deve estar entre as tags do formulário e ser do tipo "submit". Colocando o botão da forma que está, ele apenas irá fazer o redirecionamento para a página que foi colocada no href.

Segue abaixo um exemplo da página quiz.php, que irá solucionar o seu problema:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title> Super Perguntas </title>
   <style>
     h1{
        text-align: center;
        font-family:Comic-Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     }
     p{
        text-align: center;
     }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="resultado.php" method ="post">
<?php
   $nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sexoEscolhido = $_POST['sexo'];        
if($sexoEscolhido == "m")
    echo    "<h1> Seja bem vindo, $nome   </h1><br>";
else
    echo    "<h1> Seja bem vinda, $nome   </h1><br>";
echo "<br>" . $nome . ", responda a estas perguntas: <br><br>";
if($sexoEscolhido == "m"){  
 ?>

    <div id="teste">
        <p>Qual o time brasileiro tem mais mundiais?</p>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="um" value= "errada" checked>1- Santos 
 </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="um" value = "errada">2- Corinthians 
 </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="um" value = "certa">3- São Paulo </p> 
 <br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="um" value = "errada">4- Palmeiras </p> 
 <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Qual o nome do maior continente do mundo?</p>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="dois" value="certa" checked>1- Ásia 
      </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="dois" value="errada">2- Oceania </p> 
      <br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="dois" value="errada">3- America do Sul 
     </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="dois" value="errada">4- Antartida </p><br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Qual o nome da espécie do Optimus Prime?</p>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="tres" value="errada" checked>1- 
       Transformer </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="tres" value="errada">2-Autobots </p> 
      <br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="tres" value="errada">3-Decepticons 
       </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio"; name="tres" value="certa">4- Cybertroniano 
       </p><br>
        <br>
    </div>
     <br>
   <?php
   }
     else{
   ?>
<form action = "resultado.php" method ="post">  
    <div id="teste">
        <p>Qual o nome da neta do Goku?</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="um" value="certa" checked>1-Pan </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="um" value="errada">2-Videl </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="um" value="errada">3-Bulma </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="um" value="errada">4-Sakura </p><br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Qual o jogo mais jogado do mundo?</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="dois" value="errada" checked>1-Counter Strike: Global Ofensive</p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="dois" value="certa">2-League of Legends</p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="dois" value="errada">3-Fortnite</p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="dois" value="errada">4-Transformice</p><br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Qual o último campeão do campeonato brasileiro, do ano de 2017?</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tres" value="errada" checked>1-Internacional </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tres" value="errada">2-Santos </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tres" value="errada">3-Palmeiras </p><br>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tres" value="certa">4-Corinthians </p><br>
        <br>
    </div>
<br>
<?php
  }
?>
<br>
<a href="index.php">
    <button type="button">VOLTAR</button>
</a>
    <button type="submit">RESULTADO</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Realmente, colocar o botao dentro do formulário foi a chave, consegui concluir com sua ajuda, e aprendi bem mais pesquisando formas alternativas de solucionar, aqui deixo minhas mais sincera gratidão de um estudante!

Comment: @VitorGomes se a resposta do André estiver correta. Marque-a como certa. Apenas você tem esse poder.

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que os valores dos inputs do seu formulário html não estão chegando no seu arquivo quiz.php, então quando você tenta atribuir a variável com um índice que não existe no array `$_POST` acontece o erro `Undefined index`.

> `$_POST` é um array associativo de variáveis passados para o script atual   via método HTTP POST quando utilizado application/x-www-form-urlencoded  ou multipart/form-data como valor do cabeçalho HTTP Content-Type na requisição.

Antes de atribuir a uma variável um valor postado via `$_GET` ou `$_POST` você precisa checar se essa variável existe usando a função `isset()` para checar se os parâmetros POST estão sendo recebidos pelo seu arquivo PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["nome"])) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
}
```

ou ainda poderia fazer dessa forma, economizando algumas linhas:

```
$nome = (isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : null);
```

[Funções para Manipulação de variáveis - isset](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)

Recomendo que você edite a sua pergunta e adicione o conteúdo completo do seu formulário hmtl e do arquivo `quiz.php`

Recomendo também que leia sobre as funções [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) e [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) para validar e tratar os dados recebidos do usuário.